# Plotting temperature over time excel

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-equations

I am doing an uni assignment and have worked out a linear equation which plots temperature over time. I have this in a graph now but that required me to use a lot of calculations in the spreadsheet.

How can I use the basic equation and display a graph like normal graphing software would?

my equation is $y=\frac{25000*x}{1020*3770}$

I am not sure on the easiest way to put this in to an excel chart to use in a presentation

Comment: I would recommend learning something that produces graphics that make this sort of thing easy and you can generate many graphic types (excel should be able to do this too). For example, Mathematica, Maple, Maxima, Sage ... See: at http://www.wolframalpha.com, type plot (25000∗x)/(1020∗3770)

Comment: I used wolframaplha but all my data is in excel thought there might be an easier way to do it. I can use another program for my mac and drag the graphic over to powerpoint I suppose

Comment: Does this help? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fIwanUubn7Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use column `A` as $x$ and `B` as $y$. In the cells of column A, you can enter the $x$ values you like. In the B column, supposing the $x$ value is in row 1, then in B1, you can enter

```
=25000*A1/(1012*3770)
```

which calculates the corresponding $y$ value for a given $x$ value. You can then copy and paste this down column B for as many rows as you need.

Comment: If you highlight the cells in the column you want to paste in, control-d gives copy down.  The cell references are automatically updated, which is what you want here.